# Azure cost management API does not respect the desired date filters

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-cost-calculation

I am writing a program in .NET to retrieve the usage cost of a subscription. The structure of the HTTP request is this:

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/(here_goes_the_subscription_number)/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?startDate=2023-06-01&endDate=2023-06-02&api-version=2021-10-01

The problem is: No matter what dates I put in the "startDate" and "endDate", it always retrieves all the cost data of the current month from day 1 of the month. For example: If today is July 15, the request brings to me all the cost data from July 1 to July 15, regardless of the date interval I specified.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much for any feedback you could provide to this tortured soul in disguise.

Comment: Have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range. The API is different if you are using an Enterprise agreement/payasyougo or a Microsoft customer agreement. Which one do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with *@Anupam Chand*, API response differs based on the **type of subscription** that you are currently using.
>
> To retrieve the usage cost of a subscription within specific duration,
> you need to include `$filter` in query that works with only  **Enterprise Agreement (EA)** or a **pay-as-you-go** subscriptions and not supported by
> **Microsoft Customer Agreements** subscription.

If you have **Enterprise Agreement (EA)** or a **pay-as-you-go** subscription, you can make use of below query by including `$filter` to retrieve the usage cost of a subscription within specific duration:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=properties/usageStart ge '2023-06-01' and properties/usageEnd le '2023-06-02'&$top=1000&api-version=2019-10-01
```

I have one Azure account with **pay-as-you-go** subscription like below:

[image]

When I ran below query by including `$filter` with different dates, I got different **results** successfully like this:

**QUERY 1:**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=properties/usageStart ge '2023-07-01' and properties/usageEnd le '2023-07-02'&$top=1000&api-version=2019-10-01
```

**Response:**

[image: POSTMAN SNAP]

**QUERY 2:**

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=properties/usageStart ge '2023-07-01' and properties/usageEnd le '2023-07-04'&$top=1000&api-version=2019-10-01
```

**Response:**

[image: POSTMAN SNAP]

**Reference:**

[Manage Azure costs with automation - Microsoft Cost Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range)